# What happens when a user accesses to an ASP.NET MVC website during FTP publishing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, maintenance-mode

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that needs to be regularly updated. The publishing method is FTP, and the publishing process takes around 6-7 minutes.

**During this time interval**, what happens for someone who tries to visit the website?

- Is the website (in its old version) **still available**?
- May the user experience an **unexpected behavior** while navigating?
- Is there any danger for the website (e.g. **compilation error**) if a user navigates during this time?
- If the user was logged in before the publishing, is the content of its **session variables** lost?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I have an ASP.NET MVC website that needs to be regularly updated" you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Visual Studio will create a file called ***app_offline.htm*** in the destination folder. That file stays there until the process is over.

If a user tries to access the page via browser during that period, he may see a message like this:

[image]

The ***app_offline.htm*** will disappear as soon as the publishing is done.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. What about session variables ? Are they restored after end of update?